# Node voltage, diodes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, voltage

[image]

So in this circuit, When calculating $V_{D_a}$. Is this how potential difference calculated? Nodes outlined.
If yes, how come, for the right node, it's just 0.7 + 5 - 0.7??
 I'm assuming 5 - 0.7 comes from $V_o$? But why are the voltages of $D_b$ and $D_c$ are ignored? (the default diode drops of 0.7V) They're also part of the right node, aren't they?

Comment: Where is your diode? Note also that the label you have on the node in the right center of the image is obscured by the fat line you put over the image.

Comment: @Floris well, diodes were there, it's just when a diode is on, it's like a short, when it's off it's like an open circuit. But the drop across diode still remains (which is 0.7V). Here's the picture: http://i.imgur.com/I0JDf3I.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have got is a three input OR gate with the diodes being represented by what is inside the red rectangles.

[image]

The 0.7 V represents the potential difference across a forward biassed diode (when it is conducting).

So the potential difference across the top reverse biassed diode is 4.3 V and $V_{\rm DA}$ is 5 volt although I am not sure what this voltage is supposed to represent.

The equivalent voltage $V_{\rm DA}$ for the other two diodes which are forward biassed and hence conducting is zero.

**Update** as the result of a comment

The two circuits shown below are electrically identical.

[image]

Comment: I don't get it, the right node outlined by gray lines, is just one node, right? And you put 4.3 volts several times on that node, why aren't they summing up? Also, are you doing KVL when calculating $V_DA$. Isn't it just simply node voltage thing? Like, on the left of $V_DA$ it's ground, so it's 0 V. On the right you have drop across diode... and $V_o$ (0.7+5-0.7)?? Again, why aren't 4.3 are being summed up, like $V_DA$ = $0 - (0.7 + 4.3 + 4.3 + 4.3)??

Comment: @Jack I was pointing out that all those nodes were at the same potential (relative to ground) of +4.3 V. However it might have been better if I had pointed out that in fact there is only one node on the right hand side at the high potential side of the resistor. That being the case the potential of that node is +4.3 V.

Comment: How come? there are two voltage sources of 5V from $D_C$ and $D_B$, so how come they don't double the voltage for $V_0$? Like, if you do KVL for $V_o$...

Comment: @Jack Update added which I hope will help you.